# Using js to fire an onclick event from a button (to track google adwords conversions)

Tags: javascript

I have a site that I am trying to set conversions up for with Google Adwords.  I have set up the global tag and I am trying to set off the onclick event on button click with js.

The code below is my solution.  However, looking at the developer tools I am not seeing the console.log fire, so clearly there is a breakdown.

What am I doing wrong here?

The button has this code:

```
<button class="button primary" type="submit">
```

My js:

```
<script>
document.getElementsByClassName("button").onclick = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  return "gtag_report_conversion(‘https://www.somesite.com')";
  console.log(hello);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Change to getElementsByClassName to getElementByClassName if you only have 1 button

Comment: Hm, it is saying "Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByClassName is not a function
    at (index):166"

Answer (score 0):

As well as the elementsByClassName issue mentioned by @Dave - you are returning the gtag string before the console log - meaning you would never see the log - as well as the the hello in your console log needs quotes to be a string - otherwise it will be interpreted as a ariable name - that you do not have defined in the code.

I have updated to have an eventListener on the button - note the [0] which is due to the issue that Dave is refrring to - this addes the listener to the first button in the returned node list.

Note that you will still get an array of elements by using the ClassName selcttor - even if there is only one - so you need to indicate the index of [0] to target that item in the array.

EDIT - updated to use querySelector

```js
document.querySelector(".button").addEventListener('click', ()=> myFunction());

function myFunction() {
  console.log("hello");
  return "gtag_report_conversion(‘https://www.somesite.com')";

}
```

```html
<button class="button primary" type="submit">Click me </button>
```

Comment: I am seeing:

(index):166 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
    at (index):166

Comment: make sure you are using - getElementsByClassName - note the plural ElementS - Dave was wrong on that one - you cannot using the singular - you must use the plural and then either iterate over the array as he suggested - or use index[0] if there is only one button. andobviously make sure that the class name is present on the button

Comment: I am, this is what I am using:

document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0].addEventListener('click', ()=> myFunction());

function myFunction() {
  console.log("hello");
  return "gtag_report_conversion(‘https://www.somesite.com')";

}

Comment: if you have a number of buttons - then the first one is unlikely to be the correct one - you should put a unique classname / id on the button you weant to tgarget and use that in the selector query

Comment: There is only 1 button.

Comment: ok - I have just updated my solution to use a different approach - try document.querySelector(".button").addEventListener('click', ()=> myFunction());     This works in the snippet

Comment: I tried that, got this back:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at (index):166

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyse this - please read the comments in the code:

```
function myFunction() {
  return "gtag_report_conversion(‘https://www.somesite.com')";
     //the line above will just return a string which will finish the execution of this function

  console.log(hello);
     //this will not run as we have returned
     //btw, is this a variable you want to output or just a string?
}
```

Don't you want this instead?:

```
function myFunction() {
  gtag_report_conversion(‘https://www.somesite.com');
     //this should log the conversation, no need to return it's value
  console.log('hello');
}
```